# Swiping the pages with ViewPage

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to fill the page by blocks of linearlayout by data. Also I'm using ViewPager for changing pages. Every page should have its own data blocks, but now I'm getting linearlayouts that doesn't swipes out (blocks stand still when I'm swiping pages) but there is another linearlayout right above the other ones that doesn't constist data but sliding when I swipe pages.

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/page"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/page_blocks"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**table_row:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/program_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/StudyName"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Auditorium"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/StudyKindName"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/LectureTitle"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**onCreateView of ViewPage:**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row, null);
        framesContainer = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.page_blocks);
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i += 4) {
            Frame frame = new Frame(getActivity());
            try {
                frame.setStudyName(s.get().get(0).Days().get(i));
                frame.setStudyKindName(s.get().get(0).Days().get(i + 1));
                frame.setAuditorium(s.get().get(0).Days().get(i + 2));
                frame.setLectureTitle(s.get().get(0).Days().get(i + 3));
                framesContainer.addView(frame);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return view;
    }
```

Also pic: 
[image]

Is there a way to hide the empty block and make all blocks slide after the page when swiping?

Comment: Looks like I'm getting the wrong activity by new Frame(getActivity()) method. That's why linearlayouts are drawing above the pages and doesn't slide. How can I get the right activity (or context)?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using RelativeLayouts, and since you are not aligning its children elements(ViewPager and LinearLayout), they are overlapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/page"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/page_blocks"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/page" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

This line tells the viewpager that its position is going to be at the top of the RelativeLayout:

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

And this one tells the LinearLayout its position is below the viewpager:

```
android:layout_below="@id/page"
```

There are some other properties that can be set --> [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html#Position)

To be honest, I'm not sure what you are trying to do. But maybe you just need to get rid of the RelativeLayout and use LinearLayouts instead.